# swift array removeLast extremely slow

Tags: arrays, swift

Calling `removeLast` is extremely slow (it takes several minutes to pop off 77k elements). The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anybidirectionalcollection/1787473-removelast) says O(1) and I would think the implementation would simply decrement the array size. Evidently not:

[image: stack trace indicating <code>removeLast</code> calling memmove]

Why is it calling `remove(at: Int)`?

This repro case is slower than I would expect (I'm used to C++'s `std::vector` performance), but still not as slow as what I'm seeing in my code:

```
var array = [ Int ]()

for i in 0..<262144 {
   array.append(i)
}

print ("done appending") // we get here immediately

let n = array.count
for _ in 0..<n {
    array.removeLast() // popLast is also slow
}

print ("done")
```

This takes 16 seconds on my machine. An equivalent C++ program takes .002 seconds.

Comment: Can you post code of how you tested this?

Comment: Arrays are value types that copy-on-write. So it makes sense that it makes a new copy on `removeLast`. However one would think that this should be fast too.

Comment: @Fogmeister I'm trying to pull out some code for a repro without just dumping all my code. When I write a similar test case, it's fast. Something subtle is going on.

Comment: @Taylor Are you use that time spent here is caused by `removeLast`, and not `append`? Unless you use `reserveCapacity` to preallocate a sufficiently large buffer, repeatedly calling `append` will incur reallocation overhead, which could be responsible for the results you're experiencing.

Comment: @Alexander The first loop completes almost instantly. If the implementation is like std::vector then it uses a heuristic to increase the array capacity and there won't be that many reallocations.

Comment: @Taylor Yeah, it usually just doubles the size overtime an overflow would occur. log_2(n) allocations. Hmmm. I just tried this. Much slower than I would have expected... something's not right

Comment: @Taylor Could you try comparing `popLast`, and see if that behaves any better?

Comment: @Alexander `popLast` is similarly slow.

Comment: @Taylor Wow, this is very disappointing. Could you please file a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way you're testing. *No* speed test in a Debug build is meaningful in the slightest. This is why you should *always* profile *in Instruments*. It uses a Release build. For realistic results, profile in Instruments on a device. Everything else is an illusion.

So do a Release build, not a Debug build. You will see that in reality you get both `print` statements *instantly*.

Results (on my computer, not a device, because I was too lazy to take the phone out of my pocket) displaying seconds since reference date:

```
starting 506917910.056674
done appending 506917910.060245
done 506917910.069827
```

Comment: Can confirm: `swift -O test.swift` completed instantly

Comment: Silly me. I'm used to usable debug builds!

Comment: Same thing is true of memory management. Swift memory management in a Debug build in the Simulator is a big lie.